# Filtrando registros de tablas asociadas que coincidan con la sesion actual Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

He estado intentando crear filtrar los usuarios que postularon a X oferta de trabajo, pero para tener un mejor panorama explicare mi asociación y mi problema:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :enterprise
  has_many   :job_candidates
end

class JobCandidate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :job
  belongs_to  :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_candidates
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs
end
```

Tengo los usuarios `(User)` quienes postulan a los empleos `(Job)` que las empresas `(Enterprise)` publican, para esto en el momento en el que el usuario X aplica a X empleo, dentro de la tabla `(JobCandidate)` se almacena, quien postulo a la oferta `(user_id)`, y a que trabajo se postulo `(job_id)`, unicamente esos 2 campos, ahora bien, por lo tanto `JobCandidate` esta relacionado con los modelos User and Job, ahora bien dentro del dashboard de Enterprise necesito imprimir todos aquellos registros de `JobCandidate` en donde su relacion `job_candidate.user.enterprise.id` coincida con el usuario actual, sin embargo la primera idea que se me vino fue realizar un scope, pero aparentemente dentro del scope del modelo no puedo compararlo con una session actual es decir `(current_enterprise)`, por lo tanto se me viene en mente el controlador, pero no logro filtrar esos datos, algo que seria como:

```
def dashboard
  @job_candidates = JobCandidate.all.where(job_candidate.job.enterprise_id: current_enterprise.id)
end
```

Es una idea es bastante vaga, pues no logro llegar a una forma exacta de como comparar el id de las empresas de los trabajos a los que se postularon `(job.enterprise.id)` con la sesion de la empresa actual `(current_enterprise)`, la idea es filtrar tanto los trabajos como los usuarios a quienes la empresa vera quiens postularon a sus trabajos

No se si he logrado darme a entender, pero agradecere mucho puedan darme una mejor idea, saludos!

Comment: Entonces, quieres obtener todos los registros de `JobCandidate` de los usuarios (`User`) que pertenecen a la empresa (`Enterprise`) del usuario actual (`current_user`), ¿correcto?

Comment: Si el modelo `JobCandidate` solo tiene dos claves (`user_id` y `job_id`), ¿para qué quieres los registros?; ¿exactamente qué quieres mostrar en pantalla?

Comment: Saludos @Gerry! Exactamente, deseo mostrar todos los usuarios que pertenecen a la empresa del empleo que se publico, y que el ese id coincida con el id de la session actual, en pocas palabras cada empresa solo debe de ver los usuarios que postularon a esa oferta, algo como: JobCandidate.job.enterprise.id == current_enterprise.id, de esa forma, deberia filtrarme todos los JobCandidate de la empresa con el id de la session actual, sin embargo no se de que forma expresarlo para que los imprima dentro de un loop con esa condicion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener los usuarios (`User`) que postularon para un empleo específico (`Job`), sería mejor consultar directamente el modelo `User` o, bien, a través de una relación `has_many :through`, el modelo `Job`; así obtendrás todos los usuarios para un determinado empleo en un objeto `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Lo primero que deberías hacer es establecer la relación `has_many :through` en el modelo `Job`:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :enterprise
  has_many   :job_candidates
  has_many   :users, through: job_candidates
end
```

Con esta relación podrás obtener los usuarios para un empleo sin necesidad de explícitamente utilizar el modelo `JobCandidates`; por ejemplo, así podrías obtener los usuarios que se han postulado para el empleo con `id = 1`:

```
@job   = Job.find(1)
@users = @job.users
```

O, si lo prefiere en una línea:

```
@users = Job.find(1).users
```

El resultado será una colección (`ActiveRecord::Relation`) de los objetos `User` que estén relacionados, a través del modelo `JobCandidates`, con el objeto `Job` seleccionado (i.e. con `id = 1`).

Entonces, suponiendo que quieres mostrar en una página todos los empleos de una empresa en particular y que cada empleo muestre los usuarios que se han postulado, harías lo siguiente:

**Controlador**

```
def show
  @enterprise = Enterprise.find(params[:id])
end
```

Aquí asumo que llegas a la página a través de un `index` donde están todas las empresas enlistadas, donde das clic a una, la cual te llevaría a la acción `show` del otro controlador, pasando como parámetro el `id` de la empresa.

En caso que tu forma de obtener `id` de la empresa sea distinto, simplemente cámbialo en la acción del controlador que estés utilizando (en mi ejemplo la acción es `show`).

**Vista**

```
<% @enterprise.jobs.each do |job| %>
  <div>
    <h3><%= job.title %><h3>
    <ul>
      <% job.users.each do |user| %>
        <li><%= user.name %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Estoy suponiendo que el modelo `Job` tiene un atributo llamado `title` y el modelo `User` tiene un atributo llamado `name.`

El resultado será una sección (`div`) para cada empleo (`Job`), la cual contiene el listado de usuarios (`User`) que se ha postulado para ese empleo.

Comment: Obtengo un error en Gerry, te lo anexo mejor aun gist ya que es mucho mas legible, al mismo tiempo que anexo como tengo estructurada la asociacion actualmente:

https://gist.github.com/hernandezalek/4f8c0aea996416db8d13b898107cdfd5

Comment: @HectorHernandez ¿Podrías incluir la migración de la tabla `job_candidates`? El error sugiere que el problema está en el formato de la columna `user_id` en esa tabla (debe ser `integer`, no `string`).

Comment: Que safada, la vedad no me habia dado cuenta de ese error, en el tipo de datos, y va funcionando de maravilla

Comment: Para en vez de captar el usuario que postulo, sino mas bien, a la oferta q se postulo, me imagino que has_many :jobs, throught: :job_cadidates, se debe de realizar lo mismo en el modelo User? o siemrpe Enterprise? ya que como se quien postulo, falta anexar a la oferta q postulo

Comment: Bueno la verdad pesandolo bien, en realidad ni siquiera es necesario hacer eso, ya que desde el momento en el que le especifico al controller: current_enterprise.jobs, deberia arrojarme, los empleos de la session actual, solo bastaria con intentar pasar el paramtro de job.name dentro del loop job.users.each

Comment: @HectorHernandez Sí, podrías también agregar `has_many  :jobs, through: job_candidates` en el modelo `User`, lo cual te serviría para obtener todos los empleos para los que se ha postulado algún usuario, lo cual harías con `User.find(1).jobs` si tu usuario tuviera un `id = 1`.

Comment: En la vista seria algo como: @enterprise.users.each? al dejarlo con esa asociacion?

Comment: @HectorHernandez En este caso no podrías aplicarlo directamente a `Enterprise` ya que no tienes una relación (i.e. `belongs_to :user`) que te permita llamar a `users` de esa manera. Y tampoco creo que sea lo que buscas, ya que implicaría que un `User` pertenecería a una `Enterprise`, lo cual me imagino que es incorrecto.

Comment: Exactamente no tendria sentido ya que ningun usuario pertenece a una empresa